# Pandas DataFrame - How to retrieve specific combinations of MultiIndex levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I have the following DataFrame that uses a three-level MultiIndex:

```
In [1]: iterables = [[1, 2], ['foo', 'bar'], ['one', 'two']]
   ...: midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8), index=midx)
   ...: df

Out[1]:
                  0
1 foo one -0.217594
      two -1.361612
  bar one  2.477790
      two  0.874409
2 foo one  0.403577
      two  0.076111
  bar one  1.423512
      two  0.047898
```

I'd like to slice the index such that I keep all of the first level while only keeping the following combinations of the second two levels: `('foo', 'one')` and `('bar', 'two')`. That is, I'd like my output to look something like this:

```
                  0
1 foo one -0.217594
  bar two  0.874409
2 foo one  0.403577
  bar two  0.047898
```

Is it possible to do this in one line, using an attribute such as [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc), for example?

---

I know that I can take cross-sections of the desired combinations separately using the [`.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas.DataFrame.xs) function, but I'd prefer a shorter, more slice-like syntax. Specifically, having a one-liner is important for my use case.

It seems like the following should work:

```
df.loc[[(slice(None), 'foo', 'one'), (slice(None), 'bar', 'two')]]
```

But this results in a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a Boolean mask by first dropping the first index level and then using [`pd.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with a list of tuples:

```
df_masked = df[df.index.droplevel(0).isin([('foo', 'one'), ('bar', 'two')])]

print(df_masked)

                  0
1 foo one  1.510316
  bar two  0.260862
2 foo one  0.813745
  bar two  0.023386
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). Your MultiIndex has unnamed levels, but level `k` can be accessed with the special name `ilevel_k`, according to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax): "If the levels of the `MultiIndex` are unnamed, you can refer to them using special names."

```
query_string = ('(ilevel_1 == "foo" & ilevel_2 == "one") | '
                '(ilevel_1 == "bar" & ilevel_2 == "two")')

df.query(query_string)
                  0
1 foo one -0.217594
  bar two  0.874409
2 foo one  0.403577
  bar two  0.047898
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions from jpp and Peter are good. In case someone finds it useful, here is another approach using a series as a filter.

```
f = pd.Series([True]*len(midx), index=midx)
f.loc[:,'foo','two'] = False
f.loc[:,'bar','one'] = False

print(df[f[df.index]])
                  0
1 foo one -0.185593
  bar two -1.265191
2 foo one  0.490959
  bar two  0.414753
```